# its possible using fullcalendar js to setting holiday only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I trying using `fullcalendar.js` to do a calendar view thats allow user just click the day and set the holiday only.This is the interface:[image]

**The white space there, i will list out all input holiday.**
**When user add new holiday input form.**
[image]

The problem is when user can create more than one event on the day.

How to only allow user create one event on the day and when user
click the day is update the event, not create a new event?

I saw this code from http://demo.kimlabs.com/gentelella/production/calender.html.
Thank you very much.